# is it possible to put a ternary operator inside a switch? Javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, conditional-operator

is it possible to put a ternary operator inside a switch statement?

Something like this (which isn't working):

```
case "streetName" : entries[0][1] ?? entries[0][1] += `, ${value}` : value;
```

Comment: You are mixing `Ternary` (`?` + `:`) and `Nullish coalescing` (`??`).

Comment: Also, whatever you are doing, you probably should not be doing it. Ternary should be used for simple assignments. You are trying to increment a value inside it. This is just confusing and unnecessary.

Comment: It's possible when you use the correct syntax. But just because something is possible doesn't mean it should be done.

Comment: Technically, you can use the ternary operator anywhere an expression is allowed, including inside the `switch` parentheses and as a `case` value, not just in the case statement. Whatever you mean by "not working" is unrelated to using a ternary.

Comment: The previous case is: case "streetNumber" : entries[0][1] = value;

Ideally I'd like to concatenate into one variable if it exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use a single question mark and don't forget to assign the second part of the result to something:

```
case "streetName" : entries[0][1] ? entries[0][1] += `, ${value}` : entries[0][1] = value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works. Weird I've used ternaries a fair bit before but mixing with the case statement, and not knowing wether it was possible to do, seems to have made me forget the syntax